# Can you drop "a" in the set expression "il y (a) autant de chiens que d'enfants en Suisse"?

Tags: grammaire

> Impossible de savoir à quoi s'attendre précisément lorsque le diagnostic tombe : **il y autant de formes de la maladie de Crohn que de malades**. Cette incertitude fait d'ailleurs partie des éléments difficiles à vivre. Cependant, après quelques années, on parvient généralement à repérer une crise, à anticiper un minimum. Accepter les inconnues liées à cette pathologie est essentiel pour réussir à vivre relativement sereinement malgré tout.

Instead of:

> Il y **a** autant de formes de la maladie de Crohn que de malades.

I have come across far too many instances of "a" being dropped in this fixed expression to just put it down to a careless  typo. This *supposed* typo seems to slip into even some news articles where you do not normally expect to see them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No you can't drop the verb in these sentences and stay grammatical.

I suspect the large number of occurrences of this typo is due to the fact the missing letter is also the first letter of *autant* so when typing it, we make some kind of a shortcut and jump to the next word; then, while reading a faulty sentence, the brain is regenerating the missing *a* without us noticing.

This theory is supported by the fact a similar issue can be observed with ***il y aussi***, for example in this [OQLF article](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3906):

> *il n’y a pas que ses petits-enfants qui comptent; **il y aussi** sa femme.*

Comment: Interesting theory, you learnt me something. +1 :-)

Comment: @Mistalis you learnt but he taught you something

Comment: @josh Typical French mistake due to *apprendre* meaning both teach and learn.